# How to make this more functional?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Trying to write more functional javascript with the underscore library. Any thoughts on how to improve this to be more functional than imperative?

The first of each pair is a "bucket" and the second is a value, I'd like to iterate over the information and get a unique list of what is in each bucket.

```
var a = [
  ['A',1],
  ['A',1],
  ['A',1],
  ['A',2],
  ['B',1],
  ['B',2],
  ['B',2],
  ['B',4],
  ['C',6],
  ['D',5]
];

//result should be:
//  {
//     A: [1,2],
//     B: [1,2,4],
//     C: [6],
//     D: [5]
//  }

_.chain(a)
 .groupBy(function (pair) {
    var group = pair[0];
    return group;
 })
 .mapObject(function (val, key) {
    var results = _.chain(val)
                   .map(function (pair) {
                     return pair[1]
                   })
                   .uniq()
                   .value();
    return results;
 })
 .value();
```

Comment: Belongs on code review.

Comment: Is this code actually working as intended?

Answer (score 2):

```
_.reduce(a, function(memo, pair){
  var key = pair[0], value = pair[1];
  var bucket = memo[key] = memo[key] || [];
  if (!_.contains(bucket, value)) bucket.push(value);
  return memo;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
var groups = _.groupBy(a, '0');

var result = _.mapObject(groups, function(group){
    return _.uniq(_.pluck(group, '1'));
});
```

Comment: This is better than my answer. Using reduce is kinda like cheating. Your solution can be done without any assignments, which is preferable IMO.